# IntelliJ cannot connect to protected tcp Docker socket

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I want to use the [Docker integration in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html) to connect to a protected remote Docker socket:

[image: Docker Socket Configuration in IntelliJ]

As you can see in the above picture I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot connect: java.io.IOException: Channel disconnected before any data was received
```

When I set the Docker [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#secure-by-default) `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1`, `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://myhost:2376`, `DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/path/to/certs/` to the same values as in the IntelliJ configuration and try to connect via terminal its working perfectly.

Does anyone know what's causing this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you try to enter https instead of tcp?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50750 - My own investigation to this issue. Doesnt work from pycharm. After few days, I gave up and just either opened the insecure port access 2375(If I remember right) or made conda installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was like Kootli suggested in the comments to use `https` instead of `tcp` as protocol.

*Engine API URL:* `https://myhost:2376`

Comment: Please let me know what i have to specify certificate folder

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error getting IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to connect to Docker. [This page in the JetBrains docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker-connection-settings.html) gave me the answer:

> In the **General** section of your Docker settings, turn on the **Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS** option.

After making the change, it connected fine.

The Docker setting to change:

[image]

Comment: That was not an option when posting the question, because the Docker Socket needed to use TLS for security reasons. So that is not a real answer to the question.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp If it's a new option now, then it's a valid answer to solving this type of error now, even if it wasn't when the question was originally asked. Or am I misunderstanding you?