# How to connect IntelliJ Docker Integration to Docker Desktop (for Windows 10)

Tags: windows, docker, intellij-idea

When I'm trying to get the Docker integration of IntelliJ (Ultimate 2018.3.3) working together with local running Docker Desktop (Version 2.0.0.3 (31259)), I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot connect: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost:127.0.0.1:2375
caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

I found the following question: [IntelliJ cannot connect to protected tcp Docker socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808495/intellij-cannot-connect-to-protected-tcp-docker-socket)

But this solution leads to this error:

```
Cannot connect: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Enabled TLS verification (DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1) but certificate path (DOCKER_CERT_PATH) is not defined.
```

I searched for the cert path of Docker Desktop but found nothing yet because the new Hyper-V solution of Docker Desktop doesn't run docker-machine native any more.

Answer (score 22):

The solution is to enable exposing the Docker deamon on tcp:localhost:2375 without TLS.
This option can be found in general settings of Docker Desktop (Version 2.0.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

Setting / General / Expose daemon on `tcp://localhost:2375` without TLS

[image]